# Laravel view performs JS 2 times

Tags: javascript, laravel, view

I have view with code below:

```
<div>
Very bad words on Russian)
</div>
<script>console.log(123)</script>
```

When the page is loaded, "123" is output 2 times to the console. At the same time, in the panel you can see that there is only one console.log(123) in the code. Those. For some reason Laravel executed the written JS 2 times (
I hope that someone faced a similar problem) Because I broke my brain already) I would be very grateful for any help)

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It was Vue.js) Just I have first "div" with #app and it wrap all page. My vue work with this div. In result, I performs JS first time from tags SCRIPT, and second time from new Vue({el: '#app'}) =)